# Delimiting a specific column

Tags: r, strsplit

I have a similar question to this one below:

[Split column at delimiter in data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069076/split-column-at-delimiter-in-data-frame)

Except there is a new layer of complexity of having an unknown amount of delimits. I'd like to create new columns with one Item code per column.

```
                                        Item Code Transaction ID Sales
1                             16522337|10086236     3812351327  449.97
2                             21106549|24390750     3851589288   67.98
3                                      23475149     3804446998   54.99
4                                      19397324     3866373678  224.97
5                             23317326|23825351     3820764147  109.99
6                    20433128|20433140|20433165     4962022906  369.94
7                                      19506902     3835040778   10.50
8  24095014|25029701|24244086|24244271|16803155     3910007218  142.97
9                                      24036073     3887666318   22.49
10                   19972354|14519726|18168381     3757376277   98.89
```

Comment: How about this one? http://stackoverflow.com/q/35772166/903061

Comment: Thanks Greg, realized there might be an easier way to accomplish my goal. Please keep this closed.